# How to create long lived access tokens for published API in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have created apis and published using [this tutorials](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) and it is working, i want to create long lived access tokens , is there any way to create long lived access tokens??? please help me to create long lived access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Setting token to a negative value will never expires the token. Found in [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-renewAppToken).

Answer (score 0):

It can be set as long as you want when you generate the token, 3600 secs is the default. If you set it to -1, the token will never expire.

Comment: I believe -1 is the recommended way by wso2 doc. You may verify and accept it as an swer if that solved your issue. Thanks.